# Calling a C++ method pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I have the following sample C++ program that tucks away pointers to the methods in the class.  I am getting a compiler error when calling that method.

```
10     class Foo
11     {
12         void set_parm1(string) {}
13         void set_parm2(string) {}
14
15         typedef void (Foo::*set_func_t)(string);
16         struct Bar
17         {
18             string value;
19             set_func_t set_func;
20         };
21
22         map<string, Bar> parameter;
23
24         public:
25         Foo();
26         void set_value(string key, string value);
27     };
28
29     Foo::Foo()
30     {
31         Bar  temp;
32
33         temp.value = "value1";
34         temp.set_func = &Foo::set_parm1;
35         parameter["param1"] = temp;
36
37         temp.value = "value2";
38         temp.set_func = &Foo::set_parm2;
39         parameter["param1"] = temp;
40     }
41
42     void
43     Foo::set_value(string key, string value)
44     {
45         Bar temp;
46
47         temp = parameter[key];
48         this->*temp.set_func(value);
49     }
```

Questions:

1. Compiler error at line 48

   > ./test.cc: In member function `'void Foo::set_value(std::string, std::string)'`:
   >   ./test.cc:51:35: error: must use `'.*'` or `'->*'` to call pointer-to-member function in `'temp.Foo::Bar::set_func (...)'`, e.g. `'(... ->* temp.Foo::Bar::set_func) (...)'`
2. I want `set_func()` (which points to either `set_parm1()` or `set_parm2()`) to update the value of `parmX` in the map itself.  Is it possible for me get the addr of `Bar.value` (line 33) that is stored in the map parameter, so I can pass it to `set_func()`?

   If no, then what is my next option, store pointer to "Bar" in the map, as opposed to copy of Bar.  Basically use `map<string, Bar *>`.
3. Just sticking to STL (not using boost library), are there guidelines to saving a ptr to a struct/class vs storing the whole object in map.  (Of course this is assuming the struct/class does not have a pointer in itself, aka no deep copy needed when storing whole object).

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: What don't you just use std::function and std::bind?

Comment: line 48: remove the *

Comment: @ipinak And remove `this->`?

Comment: @DmitryMarkin no. Member functions need one object to be called with.

Comment: Oi. One question per question, please.

Answer (score 7):

For 1: You need to put it in brackets:

```
(this->*temp.set_func)(value);
```

For 2: You could take the address of `temp.value` (which you probably meant by `Bar.value`?), but that would be useless as it is a temporary variable and hence the address is invalid after `Foo`'s ctor finished.

For 3: I'm not really sure what you mean. You can use `std::shared_ptr` et. al. if you want to avoid copying of large/expensive objects or other means like move-semantics to reduce the overhead, but there is no general answer I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

The solution suggested by @Daniel Frey will probably work.

But the correct way of doing it in C++ (or any other object-oriented language for that matter) is with Polymorphism.

On the technical aspect, what you need to do is consider using Inheritance combined with virtual functions, instead of function pointers.

For example (based on the code in your question):

```
class Foo
{
protected:
    virtual void set_parm(string)=0;
    struct Bar
    {
        string value;
    };
    map<string, Bar> parameter;
public:
    void set_value(string key, string value);
};

class Foo1 : public Foo
{
private:
    void set_parm(string) {} // you probably wanna do something here...
public:
    Foo1();
};

class Foo2 : public Foo
{
private:
    void set_parm(string) {} // you probably wanna do something here...
public:
    Foo2();
};

void Foo::set_value(string key, string value)
{
    Bar temp;
    temp = parameter[key];
    set_parm(value);
}

Foo1::Foo1()
{
    Bar  temp;
    temp.value = "value1";
    parameter["param1"] = temp;
}

Foo2::Foo2()
{
    Bar  temp;
    temp.value = "value2";
    parameter["param1"] = temp;
}
```

Comment: +1 Note I only fixed the compilation problem, not the design problem which you kindly addressed, hence the upvote :)